# Change a date in EXCEL based on changes to other cells

Tags: vba, auto-update

I am trying to automate the updating of a status date in an Excel Worksheet based on if any changes have taken place within certain cells.  In my example, I want the date in cell "S6" to equal today's date is any of the data in cells "B6:L34" have been changed/ deleted/ info added.  I am not sure what VBA code to use or how.  Any clues? This would be for only changes within those cells on that worksheet; not changes throughout the Workbook. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into workbook/worksheet events throughout the internet. You can create private sub functions that automatically runs whenever a change is made. It sounds like you need a private sub worksheet_selection or worksheet_change event handler. Look up something simple like "workbook_open VBA excel" and you can get A great feeler for how event handlers work.

Then I suggest you to research the INTERSECT function and play around with it. It allows you to declare a TARGET variable and range for you to manipulate, basically saying that if anything happens to that range, this is how I want to manipulate the TARGET. The TARGET is basically the cell that was being manipulated within the range.

There might be other factors - but this will start you off very quickly

Answer (score 0):

This code will update the cell S6 with today's date when anything inside the range B6:L34 has been edited.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.range("B6:L34")) Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("S6") = Date
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

For this to work, make sure this code is placed within the sheet that you're using (see below):

[image]

Comment: Thank You for the reply.  I tried this but it didn't work.  I pasted it into the vba module, changed the name of the sheet ("Milestone") and tested. But it didn't update.  Any idea what I may have done wrong?

Comment: I included a screenshot in my answer to help clarify. It should work if you double click on where I have circled and paste your code there (assuming that is the sheet that you are working with).

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had a minor error and that changed it all. It is working now.